# How to add simple custom form to magento admin panel

Tags: magento

First of all let me clear what i want to do, here is my problem. I have my magento project running on server. Now my client is asking me to add a module like this, please have a look

```
http://www.chinaglaze.com/Try-On/index.html
```

Also he want that he can manage images and color codes from the Magento Admin panel. I have not much experience in magento extension development.

Please provide me reference if there is any magento extension already exist so that i can use that other wiase how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Magento frontend view which is admin manageable (with your own custom database tables) try this piece I wrote: [link](http://bluecliff.nl/news/magento-admin-manageable-frontend). Hope it suits you.

Answer (score -1):

You should add a custom module to add that.
Check this link
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_create_an_admin_form_module

Comment: Thanks Shivanand, so i will have to make my own module for this.

Comment: Yes. I hope that link will be useful for you. If you found the solution plz accept the answer